# Existence and Uniqueness of solutions to a differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I have the equation

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = 2\sqrt{x-1} = F(x)$$

Now I have to determine, given that $x(0) = x_0 \geq1$, for what values of $x_0$ admit a unique solution and what values does the equation have infinitely many solutions and "construct solutions to support my argument".

Now.

We can see that $F'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}$ which is discontinuous at $1$ and so is not continuous on some open interval about $x_0 =1$ which includes 1. hence the existence and uniqueness theorem is not satisfied.
so the general solution 
$$x(t)= 1 +(t + \sqrt{x_0-1})^2$$
is reduced to

$$x(t)= 1 +t ^2$$
we note that another possible solution is $x=1$, so there is more than one solution.

**How do I show that there are infinitely many solutions?**

when $x_0 > 1$, the conditions of the existence and uniqueness theorem are satisfied.

$$x(t)= 1 +(t + \sqrt{x_0-1})^2$$

this is reflected in the above equation, it is an injective, monotonically increasing function of time.

*What I would like to know is;
Have I answered the question?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have answered the question except for one point. You have shown that if $x_0=1$ here are at least two solutions, but you are supposed to show infinitely many. For this, given $a>0$, construct a solution $x_a(t)$ which has a certain value if $0\le x\le a$ and a different one if $x>a$. Let me know ih¡f this hint is not enough.

Comment: I think I may need something more. Sorry.

Comment: I have set the lower limit of time to some arbitrary $t_0$ in an attempt to obtain the missing piece and get $x = 1+(t-t_0)^2$ but I don't think that is what is required from your answer.

Comment: You are on the right track. $x_a(t)=1$ if $0\le x\le a$ and $x(t)=1+(x-a)^2$ if $x>a$ (my $a$ is your $t_0$.)

Comment: Ah I see, so using my version if $t \leq t_0$ then $x = 1$ and otherwise $x(t) = 1 + (t - t_0)^2$, what is the reason for this though? is it because  if  $t \leq t_0$ then then the "experiment" hasn't began? I am sorry, my intuition isn't great. I am struggling to see the reasoning behind it.